# OpenID authentication to Google Apps via Perl and Net::OpenID::Consumer fails

Tags: perl, openid, google-apps

*I asked this over on Google's support forums for Apps integration, but got zero response. Maybe somebody here can help steer me in the right direction.*

I'm trying to integrate a Perl application with Google Apps, and I'm having some trouble with the OpenID authentication. I've been using this [PHP tutorial](http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_php.html) from Google as a kind of reference, since there are no Perl examples I can find.

My initial file, index.cgi (referred by manifest.xml, and the starting point of the OpenID transaction) is as follows:

```
use Net::OpenID::Consumer;
use CGI;
# ...

my $q = CGI->new();

my $domain = $q->param('domain');
if (!$domain) {
    print $q->header(), 'Provide domain please.';
    exit 0;
}
# my website
my $root = 'http://www.example.com/';

my $csr = Net::OpenID::Consumer->new(
     # The user agent which sends the openid off to the server
     ua => LWP::UserAgent->new,
     # Who we are
     required_root => $root,
     # Consumer Key Secret from Google Apps Marketplace
     consumer_secret => 'Zzzzzz9zzAAAAA....'
);

my $claimed_id = $csr->claimed_identity(
    'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=' . $domain);

if ($claimed_id) {
    my $check_url = $claimed_id->check_url(
        # Upon validation, the user will be returned here, and real
        # work may begin
        return_to => $root . '/return.cgi',
        trust_root => $root
    );
    print $q->redirect($check_url);
}
else {
    print $q->header(), "Error";
}
```

This part seems to be working. That is, I get redirected to **return.cgi** with a bunch of `openid.*` parameters. However, at this point I get the following error:

*no_identity_server The provided URL doesn't declare its OpenID identity server*

I'm using the latest version of the Net::OpenID::Consumer module.

Here are the significant bits of **return.cgi**:

```
my $q = CGI->new();
my $csr = Net::OpenID::Consumer->new(
     ua => LWP::UserAgent->new,
     # The root of our URL
     required_root => 'http://www.example.com/',
     # Our password.
     consumer_secret => 'Zzzzzz9zzAAAAA....',
     # Where to get the information from.
     args  => $q
);

print $q->header();
$csr->handle_server_response(
     not_openid => sub {
         print "That's not an OpenID message. Did you just type in the URL?";
     },
     setup_required => sub {
         my $setup_url = shift;
         print 'You need to do something <a href="#">here</a>.';
     },
     cancelled => sub {
         print 'You cancelled your login.';
     },
     verified => sub {
         my $vident = shift;
         my $url = $vident->url;
         print "You are verified as '$url'. ** FIN **";
     },
     error => sub { die "Can't figure it out: ", @_; }
);
```

As you can imagine, I'm wanting the `verified` sub to fire, but instead I'm getting an error. Anything obvious I'm missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution, it turns out, is to switch modules. I changed to the skimpily documented [Net::Google::FederatedLogin](http://search.cpan.org/~cebjyre/Net-Google-FederatedLogin-0.5.3/lib/Net/Google/FederatedLogin.pm), and things are now working. The code is as follows (substitute *example.com* below for your actual developer's domain).

In your Google Apps Marketplace vendor profile, add the URL to **index.cgi** in the Application Manifest:

```
...
<Url>http://www.example.com/index.cgi?from=google&amp;domain=${DOMAIN_NAME}</Url>
...
```

Then add the following code to your servers.

**index.cgi**

```
use CGI;
use Net::Google::FederatedLogin;

my $q = CGI->new();

my $domain = $q->param('domain');
if (!$domain) {
    print $q->header(), 'Provide domain please.';
    exit 0;
}

my $fl = Net::Google::FederatedLogin->new(
    claimed_id => 
        'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=' . $domain,
    return_to =>
        'http://www.example.com/return.cgi',
    extensions => [
        {
            ns          => 'ax',
            uri         => 'http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0',
            attributes  => {
                mode        => 'fetch_request',
                required    => 'email',
                type        => {
                    email => 'http://axschema.org/contact/email'
                }
            }
        }
    ] );

print $q->redirect($fl->get_auth_url());
```

**return.cgi**

```
use CGI;
use Net::Google::FederatedLogin;

my $q = CGI->new();
print $q->header();

my $fl = Net::Google::FederatedLogin->new(  
    cgi => $q,
    return_to =>
        'http://www.example.com/return.cgi' );

eval { $fl->verify_auth(); };
if ($@) {
    print 'Error: ' . $@;
}
else {
    # we've authenticated and gotten attributes --
    my $ext = $fl->get_extension('http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0');
    print $ext->get_parameter('value.email'); 
}
```

(For a full sample, plus OAuth access to user data, see this [post](http://www.arbingersys.com/2010/12/integrate-your-perl-application-with.html) on my blog.)

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, [reportedly](http://groups.google.com/group/openid-perl/browse_thread/thread/38875a807657a2e7/690c7226b26373a8), this is caused by Perl missing Net::SSL, making it fail on Google's SSL URLs.

Comment: Thanks, Net::SSL on the system is version 2.84, so it's pretty current. I also use LWP to do https queries in other apps on the system, and haven't ever had a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The step where it's failing is where it performs discovery on the identifier asserted by Google's server. For some reason discovery on that identifier URL is failing. It would be helpful to know what OpenID identifier the Google server is asserting to try to debug why discovery is not working for it.

Comment: return.cgi is getting the following parameter -- openid.identity=http: //apps.example.com/openid?id=100540411240650753287 -- is this what you mean? This URL to my site doesn't in fact exist.

Comment: So Google is literally asserting http://apps.example.com/openid?id=100540411240650753287 ? The OpenID consumer code will try to fetch this URL to find out what its OpenID server is, and that'll fail if that URL is not valid. Somehow you need to convince Google Apps to assert a valid URL, but I don't know enough about Google Apps OpenID to suggest a solution there.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like. I'm not sure that Google's doing everything completely straightforward OpenID-wise. I found a Google specific module that works, so I'm using that now (see below). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what $domain is there, but you may need to escape it:

```
use URI::Escape 'uri_escape';
....
my $claimed_id = $csr->claimed_identity(
    'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=' . uri_escape($domain) );
```

Also, the consumer_secret used by Net::OpenID::Consumer has no relationship to any other secret.

Comment: I gave uri_escape() a shot, but it didn't seem to matter. $domain is something like 'apps.example.com'. I guess I misunderstood the usage of consumer_secret, but since it's only used for a nonce, I don't believe it should have affected the outcome, as it matched in both index.cgi & return.cgi. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: there are multiple versions of uri_escape()

Comment: @mhambra: but none should be needed if domain is all word characters and .